# Python oop code explanation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having issues with my assignment I cannot figure out how to modify my current code to reflect what is needed in my assignment. I have to be able to include phone numbers and jersey number with my team members name. I also have to be able to save new information. Can anyone help explain?

I want to understand where I am going wrong when it comes to getting the information to show within the name, phone, and jersey. Right now, it is only giving out outputs of `s` for the name, `h` for the number, and `a` for the jersey number. When trying to remove someone within members it does not delete.

My code initial code was the following:

```
members=['shay', 'lee']

def printMenu():
print("===========Main Menu===========")
print("1. Display Team Roster.")
print("2. Add Member.")
print("3. Remove Member.")
print("4. Edit Member.")
print("9. Exit Program.")

while printMenu()!='9':
sele=int(input("Enter Choice: "))
if sele==1:
    for i in members:
        print(i)
if sele==2:
    name=input("Enter new member's name: ")
    members.append(name)
    for i in members:
        print(i)
if sele==3:
    name=input("Enter member name to be removed: ")
    members.remove(name)
    for i in members:
        print(i)
if sele==4:
    name=input("Enter the name of the memeber you want to edit: ")
    i=members.index(name)
    name2=input("Enter the new name of the member: ")
    members.remove(name)
    members.insert(i,name2)
    for i in members:
        print(i)
elif sele==9:
    print("Have A Great Day!")
    bye=exit()
    bye
```

This is what I have tried:

```
class Member:
    def __init__(self):
        members=["shay, 702546445,69","lee,564565.89"]
        self.members=members
    def addMember(self,name,phone,jersey):
        members=self.members
        nm=[name,phone,jersey]
        self.members.append(nm)
    def display(self):
        members=self.members
        for p in members:
            print("Name= {0}, Phone Number ={1}, Jersey{2}".format(p[0],p[1],p[2]))
    def remove(self,name):
        members=self.members
        for p in members:
            if p[0]==name:
                self.members.remove(p)
    def edit(self,name,name2):
        members=self.members
        for p in members:
            if p[0]==name:
                self.members.remove(p)
                p[0]=name2
                self.members.append(p)


def printMenu():
    print("===========Main Menu===========")
    print("1. Display Team Roster.")
    print("2. Add Member.")
    print("3. Remove Member.")
    print("4. Edit Member.")
    print("9. Exit Program.")


member=Member()
while True:
    printMenu()
    sel=int(input("Selection>"))
    if sel==1:
        member.display()
    if sel==2:
        name=input("Enter new member's name: ")
        number=input("Enter new member's phone number: ")
        jersey=input("Enter new member's jersey number: ")
        member.addMember(name,number,jersey)
    if sel==3:
        name=input("Enter member name to be removed: ")
        member.remove(name)
    if sel==4:
        name=input("Enter the name of the memeber you want to edit: ")
        name2=input("Enter the new name of the member: ")
        member.edit(name,name2)
    if sel==9:
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: what is the error or problem?

Comment: Which requirement are you having trouble with? Which specific aspect of implementing the requirement? What have you tried?

Comment: You don't seem to have done any object orientated programming here.

Comment: Just a heads up StackOverflow is not a homework service... Specific questions are fine but asking someone to totally rewrite your homework is not!

Comment: So this is what I have tried and but it is not removing the names and I cannot get it to it to show the full name and phone number and jersey number  or remove the person from that list

Comment: How are these 2 snippets of code related? Which one am I supposed to execute?

Comment: sorry I reworked it based of the book and various youtube videos I found. to include oop style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Object Orientated Programming.

We create objects. Here's an example definition of an object. I called it `Member`. In Python a capital first letter normally indicates that this is a `class` definition. Which is the term used to describe the template of an object

```
class Member(object):

    def __init__(self, field_1, field_2):
        self.field_1 = field_1
        self.field_2 = field_2
```

This is an example of instantiating my `Member` object.

```
>>> member = Member(1,2)  # <- Instantiating 
>>> member.field_1        # <- Accessing a field
1
>>> member.field_2
2
```

Notice how I called the instance `member` not `Member`.

The member instance has two `attributes` that the `Member` class defined in the class `__init__` method. `field_1` and `field_2`.

That strange `self` parameter in the `__init__` method signature, would have been the `member` instance that I created. And you can see that two assignments are made. `self.field_1 = field_1`...

If you can understand all of this you may be well on your way to applying this knowledge to your problem.

Comment: Awesome! This helpoed me understand a hit more. The class is online so i am pretty much learning from youtube

Comment: Good to know it helped! I think the key here is that the `member` instance is already created by the time `__init__` is called.. So that assigning to `self` is assigning to the already created object. This is what i found difficult at the start.